# How can you change the grub default operating system from the grub menu? (i.e. without booting further)

Tags: grub

As frankly the computer I'm trying to adjust is in a very difficult and public place so the less keystrokes the better!

Comment: Remote administration ftw.

Comment: I'm not going to downvote you, I'm not going to vote to close the question, but I **AM** going to suggest you rephrase it.  The more jaded among us may be inclined to think you're trying to circumvent someone's network security / default configuration...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is there any reason you cant let it boot manually into the correct OS, then ssh'ing into to the system and editing /boot/grub/menu.lst to change the default settings

Comment: ah that's a good idea, i'll do that.

Comment: dont forget to reboot after for them to take effect